# Consume a .NET WebService which returns a DataSet with a Java Client

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, web-services, soap

I have a .NET Web Service that returns a `DataSet`.

I want to consume this Web Service in my Java client. I understand that Java doesn't have a corresponding datatype but I've heard that it's possible to manually parse the SOAP response.

How do I do this? Is there a better way to convert a `DataSet` to a Java compatible datatype?

I'm also open to suggestion to change the return type of the Web Service to something that is more compatible with my Java Client. What is the "most" compatible datatype between .NET and Java when working with database data?

Comment: WebServices encapsulate data in XML, it does not know about Datasets, just colections, strings, numbers and a few more types, did you tried to add a reference yo the service and consume it?(sorry if im unclear, i am c# programmer don't know how you usually consume web services in Java)

Comment: Problem is that DataSets are generic datatypes and the structure is not known until run time. So the WSDL document doesnt contain a description for the dataset since it could change for every method call.

Comment: Hmmm, a rule for Webservices is that the wsdl must describe the service's data, so if its known only at runtime, .net should be mas king it in some way, have you tried to open the service through a web browser, execute one of the functions and look at the outputed XML?

Comment: Ok, it has a lot of troubles with Java, int this article is an explanation about it and how to solve: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188755.aspx

Comment: set the return type of the method to be JSON. So other .net app wont bother because the webservice layer will convert the result to a dataset object eitherway but other language will parse the JSON string better. alos expecially with Dataset when it's a return as XML the column name is repeated twice for each value as for JSON it's only written once so data size wise it's better on Dataset/Datatable object.